# Determine if all markers are displayed on a Google Map V3 using MarkerClusterer

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I'm using Google Maps' [MarkerClusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html) to cluster my numerous markers.
Everything works fine, but I'd like to know if it is possible to know if, at a certain zoom level, all markers are displayed.

**Example** :
Here, I'd like my program answers  "*No, all markers are not displayed*"
[image]

But here (after some zooms), I'd like the program answers "*Yes, all markers are displayed*"
[image]

I can't find any function answering my needs in the doc linked above.
Is it possible ? If yes, do anyone give me a sample of code, or a clue ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of the [MarkerClusterer code](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js) and documentation is correct, I think you could just use the `getTotalClusters()` function, which in your second example I believe should return zero.

Comment: I thought the same, but `getTotalClusters()` never answers the expected result. For example, on my second example, there are 15 markers displayed on screen, and `getTotalClusters()` answers `10`. When I have a big zoom level with only one marker on screen, `getTotalClusters()` answers `0`... Am I badly using this method ?